# Find total number in a specific period of time SQL

Tags: t-sql, count

I am trying to find the total number of members in a given period. Say I have the following data:

```
member_id   start_date  end_date
1           9/1/2013    12/31/2013
2           10/1/2013   11/12/2013
3           12/1/2013   12/31/2013
4           5/1/2012    8/5/2013
5           9/1/2013    12/31/2013
6           7/1/2013    12/31/2013
7           6/6/2012    12/5/2013
8           10/1/2013   12/31/2013
9           7/8/2013    12/31/2013
10          1/1/2012    11/5/2013
```

In SQL I need to create a report that will list out the number of members in each month of the year. In this case something like the following:

```
Date    Members Per Month
Jan-12  1
Feb-12  1
Mar-12  1
Apr-12  1
May-12  2
Jun-12  3
Jul-12  3
Aug-12  3
Sep-12  3
Oct-12  3
Nov-12  3
Dec-12  3
Jan-13  3
Feb-13  3
Mar-13  3
Apr-13  3
May-13  3
Jun-13  3
Jul-13  5
Aug-13  4
Sep-13  6
Oct-13  8
Nov-13  6
Dec-13  6
```

So there is only 1 member from Jan-12 (member id 10) until May-12 when member id 4 joins making the count 2 and so on.

The date range can be all over so I can't specify the specific dates but it is by month, meaning that even if someone ends 12-1 it is considered active for the month for Dec.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed by creating a stored procedure to loop through the years and months. I tried to paste it in but it was too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create the following stored procedure that was able to accomplish what I needed:

```
USE [ValueBasedSandbox]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_member_count_per_month]    Script Date: 01/08/2015 12:02:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Create date: 2015-08-01
-- Description: Find the counts per a given date passed in
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_member_count_per_month] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
      @YEAR int 
    , @ENDYEAR int 

AS

DECLARE @FIRSTDAYMONTH DATETIME
DECLARE @LASTDAYMONTH DATETIME
DECLARE @MONTH INT = 1;

--Drop the temporary holding table if exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE

CREATE TABLE dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE (
      counter INT
    , start_date DATETIME2
    , end_date DATETIME2
    )


--Perform this loop for each year desired
WHILE @YEAR <= @ENDYEAR
BEGIN
    --Perform for each month of the year
    WHILE (@MONTH <= 12)
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SET @FIRSTDAYMONTH = DATEADD(MONTH, @MONTH - 1, DATEADD(YEAR, @YEAR-1900, 0))
        SET @LASTDAYMONTH = DATEADD(MONTH, @MONTH, DATEADD(YEAR, @YEAR-1900, 0)-1)

        INSERT INTO dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE(counter, start_date, end_date)
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS counter
             , @FIRSTDAYMONTH AS start_date
             , @LASTDAYMONTH AS end_date
          FROM dbo.member_table
         WHERE start_date <= @LASTDAYMONTH
           AND end_date >= @FIRSTDAYMONTH

        --Increment through all the months of the year
        SET @MONTH = @MONTH + 1

    END  -- End Monthly Loop

    --Reset Month counter
    SET @MONTH = 1
    --Increment the desired years
    SET @YEAR = @YEAR + 1

END -- End Yearly Loop


--Display the results
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE

-- Drop the temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.##TEMPCOUNTERTABLE

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
with datesCte(monthStart,monthEnd) as
(
    select cast('20120101' as date) as monthStart, cast('20120131' as date) as monthEnd
    union all
    select DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.monthStart), dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, d.monthStart))
    from datesCte as d
    where d.monthStart < '20140101'
)

select *
from datesCte as d
cross apply
(
    select count(*) as cnt
    from dbo.MemberDates as m
    where m.startDate <= d.monthEnd and m.endDate > d.monthStart
) as x
order by d.monthStart
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Paul!